# I want to send voice in SMS in twilio just like we used to send in our regular phone

Tags: twilio, sms, voice, twilio-twiml

I want to send voice message by using twilio. I can send text sms by

```
const messageResponse = await client.messages.create({
    body: req.body.message
      ? req.body.message
      : "This is auto generated message. Please do not reply.",
    from: "+16304XXXXXX",
    to: req.body.number ? req.body.number : "+91883XXXXXX",
  });
  console.log(`${messageResponse.to} : ${messageResponse.body}`);
```

this is for image in SMS

```
const messageResponse = await client.messages.create({
    body: req.body.message
      ? req.body.message
      : "This is auto generated message. Please do not reply.",
      mediaUrl: "https://demo.twilio.com/owl.png",
    from: "+1630XXXXXXX",
    to: req.body.number ? req.body.number : "+918838XXXXXX",
  });
  console.log(`${messageResponse.to} : ${messageResponse.body}`);
```

but now I want to send voice in sms.
Please help me
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

All media types are sent the same way. They need to be hosted online, so they are publicly accessible without authentication. The url is then passed in as one of the parameters to the API call, specifically MediaUrl.
Bare in mind the media needs to be of the accepted Mime types by Twilio https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/accepted-mime-types#accepted-mime-types

Comment: You can use http auth on a mediaUrl link, and you can then embed the username and password in the url like `https://username:password@example.com/image.jpg`. You can also use webhook verification to only return the media to requests made by Twilio. Check out the details here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/webhooks-security